# How to handle multiple updates that result in less and more number of records

Tags: laravel, eloquent

When multiple records are updated through the same form for a weekly schedule, the number of scheduled days and times can change. How to handle this?

schedules Table

```
id, location_id, service_id, user_id, start_date, end_date, (few more)
 1       3         2            6     2020-06-23  2020-08-23
```

schedule_day_times Table (**Before Update**)

```
id, schedule_id(fk), day_name(between 1 to 7), start_time, end_time 
1        1               2                      08:00 am     10:00 am
2        1               2                      11:00 am     02:00 pm
3        1               3                      08:00 am     11:00 am
4        1               4                      09:00 am     11:00 am
5        1               4                      12:30 pm     2:00 pm
6        1               4                      02:30 pm     4:00 pm
```

> Relationship - schedules table has many schedule_day_times

**After Update**

```
 id, schedule_id(fk), day_name(between 1 to 7), start_time, end_time 
1        1               1                      09:00 am     11:00 am
2        1               2                      11:00 am     02:00 pm
3        1               4                      08:00 am     11:00 am
4        1               4                      12:00 pm     02:00 pm
5        1               5                      09:30 am     11:00 am
6        1               5                      02:30 pm     4:00 pm
7        1               5                      05:30 pm     7:00 pm
```

Updates result in changed day_name, start_time, and end_time as in the above example.

---

Other Information - Form submit is same for both the tables.

---

What should be the best approach in this situation?

Comment: Can you include your controller update function?

Comment: Could you show me the HTML of the form?

Comment: My controller update simply  updates parent table with  $schedule = Schedule::create($scheduleRequest->validated());

Comment: @rkg
My controller update simply  updates parent table with  $schedule = Schedule::create($scheduleRequest->validated()); 
In the same controller I can update the child table through $schedule->dayTimes()

I should be able to manage the code on my own. My question is: What should be the best approach in this situation as this can involve deletion, creation, updating to reach the above (After Update result).